# Help in proof from Riemannian Geometry by Docarmo.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been working on ${\it Lemma\,5.2}$ from Riemannian Geometry by DoCarmo which establishes the existence and uniqueness of the vector field $Zf=(XY-YX)f$, given $X$ and $Y$ as differenciable vector fields. On this proof we have expressions for $XYf$ and $YXf$ as follows:

- $XYf=\sum_{i,j}a_{i}\frac{\partial b_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}+\sum_{i,j}a_{i}b_{j}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}$
- $YXf=\sum_{i,j}b_{j}\frac{\partial a_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}+\sum_{i,j}a_{i}b_{j}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{j}\partial x_{i}}$

Where $Xf=\sum_{i}a_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ and $Yf=\sum_{j}b_{j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}$. If I substract expressions of the items I obtain $$Zf=XYf-YXf=\sum_{i,j}\left(a_{i}\frac{\partial b_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}-b_{j}\frac{\partial a_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}\right).$$But DoCarmos says that this turns out to be $$Zf=XYf-YXf=\sum_{i,j}\left(a_{i}\frac{\partial b_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}-b_{i}\frac{\partial a_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}$$ as if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}$ were the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are nearly the same, up to indices. Try do like this: 
$$
Zf=XYf-YXf=\sum_{i,j}\left(a_{i}\frac{\partial b_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}-b_{j}\frac{\partial a_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}\right) = \sum _{i,j} a_i\partial_i b_j \partial_j f - \sum_{i,j} b_j \partial_j a_i \partial_i f \stackrel ! = \sum_{i,j} a_i \partial_i b_j \partial_j f - \sum_{i,j} b_{\color{red}{i}} \partial _{\color{red}{i}} a_{\color{blue}{j}}\partial_{\color{blue}{j}} f = \sum_{i,j} (a_i \partial_i b_j - b_i \partial_i a_j)\partial_j f. 
$$
or
$$
Zf =  \sum_{i,j} (a_j \partial_j b_i - b_j \partial_j a_i)\partial_i f. 
$$

The answer is
$$
\newcommand \i{\color{red}i}
Z f = \sum_{i,j} \left(a_j\frac {\partial b_{\i}}{\partial x_j} - b_j \frac {\partial a_{\i}}{\partial x_j}\right) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{\i}}. 
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for you suggestion, Now that's clear for me. The typo was mine, DoCarmo  has the same results as Boothby.